# How to restore a hidden file in Time Machine - can't find data file?

Tags: macos, time-machine

I followed the instructions in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141321/how-to-restore-a-hidden-file-in-time-machine) question but still cannot restore my address book and iCal data. I found what I thought was the data file for the address book, AddressBook-v22.abcddb, but when I tried to import it, Address Book didn't recognize it as a valid importable file. What is the filename of the correct file to import from my TM backup? And I couldn't find anything that looked like an iCal data file.

My back story is that my hard drive crashed on my iMac, and I brought home a new Macbook Air to replace it. I'm just trying to copy my Address Book and Calendar data from my external hard drive backup to the Macbook.

Comment: Can you add the link you mention in the first line?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141321/how-to-restore-a-hidden-file-in-time-machine

Answer (score 1):

Open Applescript Editor, in Applications > Utilities then copy/paste this to a new script...

```
set newHiddenVisiblesState to "YES"
try
    set oldHiddenVisiblesState to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
    if oldHiddenVisiblesState is in {"1", "YES"} then
        set newHiddenVisiblesState to "NO"
    end if
end try
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles " & newHiddenVisiblesState


tell application "Finder"
    set theWindows to every Finder window
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theWindows
        set this_item to item i of theWindows
        set theView to current view of this_item
        if theView is list view then
            set current view of this_item to icon view
        else
            set current view of this_item to list view

        end if
        set current view of this_item to theView
    end repeat
end tell
```

Then Save as an application, which you can then just double-click to toggle showing/hiding invisible files.

You don't need to kill the Finder for this toggle, a refresh is sufficient - & faster.