# Determine com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles status using command line?

Tags: terminal, finder, applescript, command-line, bash

Is there a way that I can grab the status of `com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles` in command line?

I switch between `AppleShowAllFiles` `yes` & `no` frequently, I want to write a `.command` file to check if it's `yes` then switch to `no` and vice versa. I now get stuck at query the status of `AppleShowAllFiles`.

Comment: It sounds like this script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206008/toggle-appleshowallfiles-with-a-simple-bash-script

Comment: The question is slightly different, but this includes several methods, covering several macOS versions [the method changes depending on OS] - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258733/how-to-show-hidden-files-on-mac-without-terminal/

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for comment from @Yoric

I found the answer from [stackoverflow @Carter Allen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206008/toggle-appleshowallfiles-with-a-simple-bash-script)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#toggle AppleShowAllFiles

current_value=$(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles)
if [ "$current_value" = TRUE ]
then
  defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
else
  defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
fi

killall Finder
```

Comment: FWIW The `AppleShowAllFiles` _key_ by default does not exist, so as coded the script fails if it had never been set previous. Also you didn't say what version of OS X/macOS you're running however, this is no longer needed since (IIRC) macOS Sierra and later has the keyboard shortcut of `⇧⌘.` to toggle the state of hidden files as needed.