# Hidden files & folders after executing Killall Finder command

Tags: folders

[image]

As the picture depics some of my folders turned grey after I executed Killall Finder command. For your information, I run a macOS 10.14.6.
Do anyone know what this means, and how to get it back to normal again?

Thank your for your time

Yoenca

Comment: They're hidden files & folders. method to return to normal view depends on what OS you're on. Can you add that info to your question?

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly! I added that information in my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're hidden files & folders.

Since Sierra you can toggle visibility simply using  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>.</kbd>  [period]

Prior to Sierra you would need to toggle visibility in Terminal or by script & then kill the Finder to make the changes register.

See [How to show hidden files on mac without Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258733/how-to-show-hidden-files-on-mac-without-terminal) for the scripted method.