# Files created by Terminal are not visible in my Finder

Tags: macos, command-line, git, invisible-files

So I've been trying to create a text file using Git, I punched in the command "touch home.html", then I punched in the command git "add home.html", then I input "git status" and the file doesn't want to appear, I have relaunched the finder multiple times, nothing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Excellent edit. Shift command . will make files and folders with a . visible.

Comment: In Catalina I've frequently had newly created files not appear in the Finder. Even Safari downloads & new Pages or Numbers documents. If the creating application has a Show in Finder action (as Safari does) that will reveal it. Otherwise relaunching the Finder (which is a pain) makes them visible for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running `git status` in the wrong repository (your home directory, `~`, i.e. `/Users/adam`). You need to move into the repo that you want to act on, i.e. `cd ~/Desktop/Tools/Git/MyFolder`, or a subdirectory of this, and *then* run `git status`.

You've created the `home.html` file in `~`.

You must have run `git init` on your home directory or a parent of it, i.e. `/Users/adam`, `/Users`, or `/`. The first is most likely, as the others would require use of `sudo`. You can forget about / get rid of this repo by running `rm -rf .git` within that directory.

---

I encourage you to learn the basics of Git by watching [this video](https://youtu.be/U8GBXvdmHT4).

Here's a good video on [Linux terminal basics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id3DGvljhT4) as well. macOS isn't Linux, but it's Unix-based, just like Linux, so the principles are the same; the knowledge directly applies to macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use text edit to save a text file in that finder window.

Remember, Finder hides all files and folders with a . by default but you have an easy key shortcut to toggle that.

- [How to show hidden files on mac without Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258733/how-to-show-hidden-files-on-mac-without-terminal)

My thinking is you have nothing amiss in the graphical side, but you’ll want to troubleshoot a little using purely command line tools or purely graphical tools to avoid mixing idioms and troubleshooting steps.

For the next edit of your question, be sure to state where you are working. A folder on your desktop is ideal to avoid permissions errors if your git is elsewhere.

Comment: My folder is on the desktop as follows --> Desktop/Tools/Git/MyFolder/.git

Comment: Aah. I’ll link to the command to show hidden files.

Comment: I have tried using the shortcut of shift+cmmd+. , the .git folder just appears and disappears to get it back up.

Answer (score 0):

The files to be tracked and `.git` folder need to be in one folder.

```
Myfolder
 |- .git
 |- home.html
```

Use `cd` to navigate. Use `man cd` in case there is a doubt.

Examples:

```
>>> pwd
~/Desktop
>>> cd Tools/Git
>>> pwd
~/Desktop/Tools/Git
>>> cd Myfolder
>>> pwd
~/Desktop/Tools/Git/Myfolder
```

Now use `touch` to make the HTML file and see if git can see it, and add it to tracking.

http://git.github.io/git-reference/basic/

### File Management

> then I input "git status" and the file doesn't want to appear,

Use `>` operator to send the output of any command in Terminal to a txt or log file.

This command creates an empty text file named `abc` on Desktop.

```
touch ~/Desktop/abc.txt
```

This command sends the output of `git status` to a file `status.txt`, you can change the location and filename.

```
>>> git status > ~/Desktop/status.txt
```

This command opens any txt/rtf/log file at the given path with TextEdit.app.

```
>>> open -a /Applications/TextEdit.app ~/Desktop/status.txt
```

https://linuxhandbook.com/create-file-linux/

Comment: Visibility of hidden files is the issue here unless I’m missing something.

Comment: They made the html file in `~/` (see the bash prompt in Terminal) and the git setup is three folders deep. (see finder screenshot)

Comment: right now, there are two gits, one in `~/` and another in  `~/Desktop/Tools/Git/Myfolder`

Comment: okay maybe they want `git status` 's output to go to a txt file, instead of Terminal.

Comment: I want the txt file to appear, I just did the git status > ~/Desktop/status.txt, still nothing appears

Comment: @AdamCiwinski  Run `open ~/Desktop/status.txt`

Comment: open ~/Desktop/status.txt, it worked and it opened in the terminal.

Comment: so, in short, I should do the following, open ~/Desktop/Tools/Git/MyFolder/example.txt

Comment: @AdamCiwinski What is example.txt ?

Comment: just a file to create

Comment: @AdamCiwinski https://linuxhandbook.com/create-file-linux/

Comment: To summarise quickly, we can't get it to open on the folder only on the desktop? , and the file name has to be status.txt?

Comment: RE: "This command creates an empty text file on Desktop. `echo > ~/Desktop/abc.txt`" ... No it does not create an empty file, however, and assuming the target doesn't already exist,  `touch ~/Desktop/abc.txt` creates an empty file, 0 bytes. The `echo > ~/Desktop/abc.txt` _command_ creates a 1 byte file with a line feed character (`0A`). It also overwrites an existing file of the same name if it already exists.

Comment: @user3439894 as if the question displayed enough knowledge (and clarity) of such intricacies. I chose to give the simplest method.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for correcting me though, learnt something new today.

Comment: Doesn't matter what intricacies the OP shows, although it did state that "touch home.html" was used to create the file. What matters is you're making a statement that is not factually true!